# How to hide aria-required = "true" field by js in checkout magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs

I add these fields using custom modules, so that when "Persoana Fizica" is clicked, these fields are hidden and will not affect the magento's data transmission. And when I click on "Firma" the fields are displayed and function as usual and I want to do this in js.
[image]

[image]

> my js

```
define([
    'knockout',
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator'
], function(ko, $, Component, Abstract, validator) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Show_Field/form/element/radio',
            createNewAccount: false

        },

        click: function(data, event) {
            this.change(event.target.value);

            return true;
        },

        change: function(value) {
            if (value === 'private') {
                $("div[name='shippingAddress.show_custom_field[show_osc_denumire_firma]']").hide();
                $("div[name='shippingAddress.show_custom_field[show_osc_cui]']").hide();
                $("div[name='shippingAddress.show_custom_field[show_osc_nr_reg_com]']").hide();
                $("div[name='shippingAddress.show_custom_field[show_osc_denumire_firma]']").find("input").attr('aria-required', 'false');

            } else if (value === 'business') {
                $("div[name='shippingAddress.show_custom_field[show_osc_denumire_firma]']").show();
                $("div[name='shippingAddress.show_custom_field[show_osc_cui]']").show();
                $("div[name='shippingAddress.show_custom_field[show_osc_nr_reg_com]']").show();
            }
        }

    });
});
```

> html

```
 <div class="customer-group-add"><h2>Grupul de clienți</h2></div>
<div class="switch-field" afterRender="change('private')">
    <div class="switch">
        <input type="radio" name="order_type" id="radio-private" value="private" checked="checked" data-bind="click: click">
        <label for="radio-private" data-bind="i18n: 'Persoana Fizica'"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="switch">
        <input type="radio" name="order_type" id="radio-business" value="business" data-bind="click: click">
        <label for="radio-business" data-bind="i18n: 'Firma'"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added plugins according to this tutorial [link checkout field magento 2](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html)

anyone has any ideas please help me. thanks